# Can we use MPI for HPC applications on the cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, virtual-machine, mpi, hpc

MPI is more suited to homogenous enviroments , What would I have to do to be able to run HPC applications that use MPI on Amazon Cloud, My understanding being that my application maybe allocated heterogenous virtual machines. What are the perfomance issues that I will encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of investment in this area, and the "state of the art" is changing rapidly. While my answer is reasonable today, that may change over the coming few quarters.

The biggest performance issue will be latency:  latency to the memory, latency to the interconnect, and latency to the file system.  Bandwidth is also an issue, but not nearly as noticeable as latency.

The next biggest performance issue is the lack of support for "common" HPC technology like DMA/RDMA, GPU's, and other hardware accelerators.  While not every cluster will have these, if you are accustomed to the performance gains of these kinds of technology the VM environment will be that much worse by comparison.

Comment: There is an increasing quantity of benchmarking results and HPC specific instance availability. http://glennklockwood.blogspot.co.uk/2013_12_01_archive.html is a good post and blog (also has how to set a HPC cluster in EC2 in the archive), as is http://blog.rescale.com/mpi-latency-on-google-compute-engine/ examining GCE.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that as of right now, Amazon EC2 does not support broadcast or multicast in any form. So if your MPI implementation uses BC/MC (e.g. for collective calls, or even just under the hood), it will not be usable on your cloud instances.

Comment: Thanks Suszterpatt and Stan, as a follow up, I'm interested mostly in the extra communication costs incurred by MPI based applications if they are moved to the cloud. Is a software solution to this challenge possible? Would it be possible to have workarounds for the cloud limitations?

Comment: EC2 is being used for MPI, including applications that use broadcast (MPI_Bcast). People are using it. The performance will vary according to the instance types being used.  Fundamentally, it does work - and hence to say "not usable" is not correct - even if the performance is not ideal for all applications.

Comment: @David: I suppose I could have been clearer. EC2 does not support the transmission of broadcast/multicast network packets. This is an entirely different network layer from the one MPI operates on, and has nothing to do with `MPI_Bcast`. An MPI implementation can of course use unicast packets only, and such implementations will of course work on EC2.

Answer (score 0):

We also needed broadcast and multicast support, so we modified the open source n2n vpn software solution and it works well for us.

https://www.buckhill.co.uk/blog/how-to-enable-broadcast-and-multicast-on-amazon-aws-ec2/2